# remove text between punctuation within string eg. ´Marc Colours` with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following string from which I'd like to remove the string which is between these two punctuation marks ´`:

```
Socken ´Marc Colours` aus Baumwollkomposition
```

so that I am left with:

```
Socken aus Baumwollkomposition
```

How could I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

**Snippet**

```js
var s= "Socken ´Marc Colours` aus Baumwollkomposition"

s= s.replace(/ +´.+` +/g,' ');
alert(s);
```